# woocommerce stored variable

Tags: loop, plugins

In wordpress, all information can be retrieved via `$post` or `wp_query`, in woocommerce, is there something similar? I want to display information of each product, on a page next to the picture. I have two questions.

1. How can i get to know, which variable does woocommerce uses to store the data.
2. In General, if we want to know the meta of any post,page, how can we pull it aganist each id, where id is generic (we don't know, its dynamic like `$post->ID`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `$woocommerce`, which is is crucial. Several classes stored into this, see [woocommerce class reference](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/class-reference/) and additionally [WC API Docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/).

If you're looking for product information:

```
$product = get_product( $post->ID );
```

is certainly a good entry point. If you're already on a product page or generally in the wc loop, you often have `$product` already available.

Another thing to add is, wc product(s) are are just a custom post type, so you can do a lot by using wordpress core functions - like:

```
$all_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
echo $all_meta;
```

But for some things you need or at least it's easier to use wc functions, to know these you have to read the plugins [documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/), e.g. [useful functions](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/useful-functions). Same applies to [action and filter hooks](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/).

Generally, take a closer look at the linked - and the not linked - information, the source and the variables/objects themselves to get deeper into that.

Comment: i got this out, when i did `print_r` http://awesomescreenshot.com/06222evvc2 how i can use it get other things, like content in my query?

Comment: You have to read up on the necessary basics yourself. @Nofel I've seen you have some answered questions you haven't taken care of, accepting answers and so on, can you do this please.

Comment: u need to give me coaching classes in woo :), not sure how i get product description, though i understood the links you provided me for API and classes.

Comment: The description is the `post_excerpt` - take a look [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96576/changing-woocommerce-product-description) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479712/woocommerce-description-in-products-page). @Nofel Btw, by taking care of questions, I didn't just mean this one, you have others, doesn't have to be now, but if you got the time go through them.

Comment: i would use post_exceprt, but i am using shortcode, so i want description do come within that shortcode.

Comment: New problem, new question, but before you ask take a look at the source, where the shortcode is construted and try figure it out yourself. @Nofel

Comment: if i was that much intelligent, i wouldn't be asking question and doing it myself. so pls guide

Comment: @ialcin, still haven't been able to figure out, how to display product description.

Comment: Take a look into `class-wc-shortcodes.php`. Besides that, like I said, new problem, new question. Thanks. @Nofel